# Heroku ps:exec changes get reset after server restart

Tags: heroku

I wanted to create/change/command directly to the heroku app through heroku CLI, ps:exec command.

For example, I actually tried to update an spree(ecommerce framework written Rails) app I created using Heroku button. After I created the app with Heroku button, I found I need an extension,
spree_digital to create digital product. So I tried following steps:

```
heroku ps:exec -a spreeapp
$ # install nano editor here
$ nano Gemfile # added a line: gem 'spree_digital', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_digital'
$ bundle install 
$ bundle exec rails g spree_digital:install # and no error. 
$ exit
heroku ps:restart # the git repo says server restart is required so

heroku ps:exec -a spreeapp # and test if that the Gemfile is same as the line added one 
$ cat Gemfile # and I found that the file I changed didn't change..
```

I'm new to Heroku, your each comment must be fuge help for me. Thanks.